# One class to call method from all other classes in directory

Tags: php, design-patterns

Sorry for a bit misleading title but I don't quite know how to ask that better.

I have a directory with classes doing same job but with different implementation. They all look like this:

```
class someClass {
    private static $variable=12345; 
    public static function someTask($keyword){
            ...
            return array();
    }
    private function pf() {...}

}
```

The methods are taking same arguments, and returning array of the same structure.

I'd like to create one class to be able to call selected classes form that folder (and maybe each of them) combine their result, sort it by some criteria end return.

I thought of strategy pattern, but as far as I know it goes like :

```
$obj = new Context();
$obj->setStrategy(new ConcreteStrategy1);
$obj->getStrategy()->task(); // => „Strategy 1”
$obj->setStrategy(new ConcreteStrategy2);
$obj->getStrategy()->task(); // => „Strategy 2”
```

Each time I want to call another class I have to change it manually. That will leave me using foreach on some array of classes (strategies) names. Is that the right way to go? Also please help me find better title for that question because that one is misleading.

Comment: why not one class with more methods, or method(s) with variables

Comment: It would be very long class, and bit messy. And I think function to call all methods is considered bad practice.

Comment: Method with variable to choose implementation would also be very long and even more mess.

Comment: our pdf class has 40k lines :-). but really its wild guessing here, its impossible (for me at least) to give an "answer" based on the information provided

Comment: What info will help?

Answer (score 1):

Strategy pattern it's just an algorithm that we extracted and put into some method. Then we pass the algorithm we need into context and use it there.

If you want to have one class that processes different strategies and combine their result I think [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) will be better.

Comment: [link](http://imgs.g4estatic.com/design-pattern/gof/Visitor.png)
In this pattern the concrete classes would be my classes doing similar task but in different ways, but what would be the visitor? And would I have more than one visitor like in this link ?

Comment: You can have as many visitors as you need. Any visitor just process some strategies set and apply each strategy from the set. An order and rules you can implement in concrete visitor.

Comment: Hm, that sounds like what I need. I will try to implement your idea tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a working solution

```
class SearchEngine {
    public $instances=array();

    public function __construct() {
        $inputSites = $this->importClasses(); //import all classes in directory
        foreach ($inputSites as $site) {
            $classname = 'API\\' . $site . "Api";
            $startegyInstance = new $classname();
            array_push($this->instances,$startegyInstance);
        }
    }

    public function searchByTitle($keyword) {
        $results = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($this->instances); $i++){
                //this searchByTitle is not recursion
                $next = $this->instances[$i]->searchByTitle($keyword);
                $results=array_merge($results,$next);
        }
        return $results;
    }
    private function importClasses($classesToImport){
        foreach ($classesToImport as $class) {
            $imp="API/".$class."Api.php";
            require_once ($imp);
        }
    }
}
```

(I cut less significant details)
In classes directory I have interface and classes. 
This solution works. I have not enough experience to judge it optimal or good.